# Python GUI TKinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making an interface for my e-learning question which is on easy difficulty. is there anything wrong with the code? It keeps on saying there is an error on line 21. Whats the mistake?

```
import Tkinter
MathsEasyLevel1 = Tkinter.Tk()
MathsEasyLevel1.geometry("320x260")
MathsEasyLevel1.title("Mathematics Easy")
total = 0

getanswer = Tkinter.IntVar()


def userinput():
    Answer1 = getanswer.get()
    if Answer1 == 8 :
        total = total + 1

    else :
        total = total
        MathsEasyLevel1.withdraw()
        MathsEasyLevel1.deiconify()
    return

LabelName = Tkinter.Label (MathsEasyLevel1, text="Question 1", font("Impact",20)).grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="new")

LabelName = Tkinter.Label (MathsEasyLevel1, text="State the number of edges in a cube")
LabelName.pack()
TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (MathsEasyLevel1, textvariable= getanswer)
TxtBoxName.pack()

MathsEasyLevel2 = Tkinter.Tk()
MathsEasyLevel2.geometry("320x260")
MathsEasyLevel2.title("Mathematics Easy")
MathsEasyLevel2.withdraw()

BtnName = Tkinter.Button (MathsEasyLevel1, text="Proceed", command=userinput).pack()
```

Comment: I would be better if you add the error msg in your stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems I can see. Line 21 (`LabelName = Tkinter.Label (MathsEasyLevel1, text="Question 1", font("Impact",20)).grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="new")`, I presume) takes `font` as an argument in the form `font = ("Impact",20)`, so your corrected code for this line would be:

```
LabelName = Tkinter.Label (MathsEasyLevel1, text="Question 1", font=("Impact",20)).grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="new")
```

Also, you are assigning the outcome of the `grid` method you are running to LabelName. You probably want to be doing this:

```
LabelName = Tkinter.Label (MathsEasyLevel1, text="Question 1", font=("Impact",20))
LabelName.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="new")
```

This way you can reference `LabelName`, now the actual label, multiple times.

You also use the same variable name, `LabelName`, for two different `Label` widgets. This means a reference to the previous one is not kept which could cause problems at some stage. Another problem is that you mix the use of the `grid` packing method and the `pack` packing method in the same window, which is [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28217012/5539184). Try this instead:

```
LabelName1 = Tkinter.Label (MathsEasyLevel1, text="Question 1", font=("Impact",20))
LabelName1.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="new")
LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (MathsEasyLevel1, text="State the number of edges in a cube")
LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (MathsEasyLevel1, textvariable= getanswer)
TxtBoxName.grid(row=2,column=0)
```

Obviously you can change the `rows` and `columns` as you want. The rest of your code looks fine to me!

Comment: can you please help me to figure out the problem below? Thanks

Comment: @MohdFareezuanKechik If you found my answer helpful feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the tick!