# _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by packenter code here

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a child widget based on Entry widget.
Unfortunately it's not working as I think it should.
From the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "SOLVE"
        self.hi_there.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.QUIT = tk.Button(
            self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=self.master.quit)
        self.QUIT.grid(row=1, column=2)

        # self.number_box = tk.Entry(self) # This is working
        self.number_box = NumberBox(self)  # this is not working
        self.number_box.grid(row=2, column=1)


class MainWindow():

    def __init__(self):
        #self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.app = Application()
        self.app.master.title("SUDOKU")
        self.app.master.minsize(width=WINDOW_WIDTH, height=WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.app.master.maxsize(width=WINDOW_WIDTH, height=WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.app.mainloop()


class NumberBox(tk.Entry):

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):

        super().__init__(cnf, kw)
        #self.text = tk.StringVar()


window = MainWindow()
```

I get an error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:/workspace/python/sudoku/gui/guitk.py", line 42, in <module>
        window = MainWindow()
      File "E:/workspace/python/sudoku/gui/guitk.py", line 28, in __init__
        self.app = Application()
      File "E:/workspace/python/sudoku/gui/guitk.py", line 11, in __init__
        self.createWidgets()
      File "E:/workspace/python/sudoku/gui/guitk.py", line 22, in createWidgets
        self.number_box.grid(row=2, column=1)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2057, in grid_configure
        + self._options(cnf, kw))
    _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by packenter code here`

When I use Entry class directly (not the NumberBox, see commented line), code is working. What do I wrong with inheritance from Entry that my class is not working properly.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Pretty good question otherwise.

Comment: If I replace self.pack() by self.grid(), your code is working on my computer(Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Self.pack() is working, but this is not solution for me. I want to use grid layout.

Comment: In the code you posted, there is a self.pack...

Comment: Yes, it was the only one occurrence of self.pack(), I forgot to change it, anyway strange that it was working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use geometry manager pack inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584325/cannot-use-geometry-manager-pack-inside)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `super()` call looks wrong. You need to pass the parent widget and pass unpacked keyword arguments, like this:

```
super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
```