# Cannot Use Geometry Manager Grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm writing a small application, and I get this error:

> cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



LARGE_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 16)
NORMAL_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 12)



def popup(title, string):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.geometry('300x100')
    popup.wm_title(title)

    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=string)
    label.pack(pady=10)

    b1 = ttk.Button(popup, text='Okay', command=lambda:popup.destroy())
    b1.pack(pady=10)

class FECapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default='icon.ico')
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, 'Family Entertainment Center Management System')

        menu = tk.Menu(container)

        file = tk.Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label='Login', command=lambda:popup('Not supported', 'This function is not supported yet.'))
        file.add_separator()
        file.add_command(label='Save Changes', command=lambda:popup('Not supported', 'This function is not supported yet.'))
        file.add_separator()
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=lambda:exit())
        menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)

        navigate = tk.Menu(menu)
        navigate.add_command(label='Home', command=lambda:self.show_frame(StartPage))
        navigate.add_command(label='Employee List', command=lambda:self.show_frame(Page1))
        menu.add_cascade(label='Navigate', menu=navigate)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menu)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, Page1):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F]=frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        label1 = ttk.Label(text="Oops!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        #label1.pack(side='top', fill='y', expand=True)
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ns')

        label1 = ttk.Label(text="There doesn't seem to be anything here right now.", font=NORMAL_FONT)
        #label1.pack(side='top',fill='y', expand=True)
        label1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ns')

class Page1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        listbox = MultiListbox(self,[('Row 1', 1, 'Item1'),('Row 2', 2, 'Item2'),('Row 3', 3, 'Item3'),('Row 4', 4, 'Item4')],['Row', 'Row (int)', 'Christmas List'])
        listbox.pack()


#Since tkinter has no multicolumn listbox, I suppose I'll make my own...
class MultiListbox(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, data, headings):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.data=data

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=headings, show='headings')
        for head in headings:
            self.tree.heading(head, text=head)
        self.tree.pack()



app = FECapp()
app.geometry('1280x720')
app.mainloop()
```

It gets fussy in StartPage.__init__() where I start to add the labels using grid, but I can't see anywhere that I'm using pack in StartPage or even on StartPage. Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use geometry manager pack inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584325/cannot-use-geometry-manager-pack-inside)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The widgets in your pages have the wrong parent. You aren't specifying a parent so it defaults to the root window, and you are using `pack` in the root window.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that for so long. Works great now.