# tkinter canvas gui does not load

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm a new programmer who am relatively new at using classes and  Tkinter. I've had a problem where my Tkinter window won't pop up nor would it show any errors.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import Canvas, Button

root = Tkinter.Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=360, height=360, bg="white")
canvas.grid()

color = canvas.create_oval(100, 100, 160, 160, fill = "white")

def changeColor(x):
    canvas.delete(color)
    c = canvas.create_oval(100, 100, 160, 160)
    canvas.itemconfigure(c,fill = x)


pink = Button(root, text = "This is just a button",changeColor("pink"))
pink.pack()

brown = Button(root, text = "This is brown",changeColor("brown"))
brown.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I wanted to make a program where the color of the oval in the canvas changes according to the button. Any advices on how to fix this are greatly appreciated!

Comment: make sure the title is a question, not "asking for advice"

Comment: Yes it is, I updated it but to no avail...

Comment: I can't get this code to run at all, there are several clear error messages. Which version of python 2 are you on? You should not mix `grid` and `pack` in the same canvas (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584325/cannot-use-geometry-manager-pack-inside)).

Comment: its python 2.7 not 1.0

Comment: I see 3 major issues. Firstly the pack/grid issue (see link in previous comment), the lack of a `command` parameter when creating the `Button`s and the fact that you dont pass a function as the parameter you intend for the `command`. I get a clear error, could your environment be hiding the errors from you? Try [this](https://ideone.com/uQj1mx) does it fix it?

Comment: It did. Seems like I missed a simple code. Thanks alot

Comment: There's no reason to delete `color` in `changeColor`, nor to create a new oval. You can just use `canvas.itemconfigure(color,fill = x)`. However, as noted in the previous comment, you can't use `changeColor("pink")` as a command.  You have to use a function name, like `changeToPink`, not a function call, not even `changeToPink()`.  (You can also have changeColor return a function, as Paul Rooney showed, but you may not have gotten up to this yet.)

Answer (score 1):

I would be worried if your environment is hiding the `tkinter` error messages from you. If you are in this situation again, I suggest running your code outside the IDE/environment if possible.

Anyway here is the code with the errors that are stopping it from running fixed.

1. Do not use `grid` and `pack` in the same master window.
2. Add a `command` parameter to the `Button` constructors.
3. Pass a function as the parameter to command, I changed what you had to use a closure to allow you to still specify the color parameter. It's basically just creating a function inside another function and returning that inner function, with some preloaded state (i.e. `x`), to be called later.

code:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import Canvas, Button

root = Tkinter.Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=360, height=360, bg="white")
canvas.grid()

color = canvas.create_oval(100, 100, 160, 160, fill = "white")

def changeColor(x):
    def f():
        canvas.itemconfig(color, fill = x)

    return f


pink = Button(root, text = "This is just a button", command=changeColor("pink"))
pink.grid()

brown = Button(root, text = "This is brown", command=changeColor("brown"))
brown.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Also note, as suggested in comments, you don't need to delete and recreate the oval. You can just reconfigure the existing one.

Comment: @Newbie did this answer your question? If so consider accepting it by clicking on the tick.