# Tkinter example for multiple frames, grid error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using below example, found on this portal. And try to add listbox. I know that I can use pack, instead grid, but pack is quite messy, and with grid I can be more specific.

```
 import tkinter as tk
 TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")
 class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        '''Show a frame for the given class'''
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()


 class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page",  font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
 class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button.pack()
 class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button.pack()
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

And for example  I want add this to PageTwo class. But I don't want to use .pack.

```
    lbox = tk.Listbox(self, height=10)
    lbox.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5)
    s = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=lbox.yview)
    s.gird(column=1, row=1, sticky=("s","e"))
```

And I getting this error

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/Mariusz/OneDrive/Projekty/Python/himan/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mariusz/OneDrive/Projekty/Python/himan/main.py", line 198, in <module>
    app = Himan()
  File "C:/Users/Mariusz/OneDrive/Projekty/Python/himan/main.py", line 44, in __init__
    frame = F(container, self)
  File "C:/Users/Mariusz/OneDrive/Projekty/Python/himan/main.py", line 132, in __init__
    lbox.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2057, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .52613520.52708464 which already has slaves managed by pack

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix `pack` and `grid` together within the same *container*. It is *possible* to mix them in different containers, but I'd **highly** recommend staying with **only** one of these geometry manager.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267140/python-pack-and-grid-methods-together) for some more help.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use only `pack` or only `grid` inside of `PageTwo` you're fine. As the error message is telling you, you're attempting to use both at the same time. If you want to use `grid` inside that class, make sure you use *only* `grid` for children of `PageTwo`.