# why ".grid" doesn't work for my coding?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
class RehabArm(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="nurse.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Rehabilitation Arm")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save Settings",
                             command = lambda: popupmsg("Not supported just yet"))
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        #logo=tk.Icon(filemenu, file="home.ico")


        helpmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Tutorial", command=tutorial)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        self.frames = {}

        #add each page here
        for F in (WelcomePage, StartPage, ExitPage, DetailsPage, ExercisePage,
                  ActivePage, PassivePage, CommentPage, SavePage, PageThree): 

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") #sticky north south east west

        self.show_frame(WelcomePage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class WelcomePage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome to Physiotherabot", font= SUPERLARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)






        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Start",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        #when using button1.grid,, it not giving any error,,,but keep loading
        button1.grid(row=1, column=1) #side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Exit",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ExitPage))
        button2.pack() #side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True
```

If using `button1.pack`, it can run smoothly, I try to configure row and column, but cannot find the suitable place because it keep loading when I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `.pack()` and `.grid()` to align widgets in the same container (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17267402/4084269)).

So in `WelcomePage` you need to choose one of them to align `button1` and `button2`.

Comment: thank you soo much,,, i always forgot to change the label.pack to label.grid... now i can use grid.. but i have one more problem,, i cannot include image ,, can you help me

Comment: logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='home.ico')
button.config(image=logo, compound='left')

Comment: i try the above coding,, there is no error,,but the image wont show

Comment: You have to keep a reference to your button image, for it to be properly displayed (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm). You can do this by adding `button.logo = logo` after `button.config(...)`

Comment: Finally, please accept the answer if it fixed your problem :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer