# Python tkinter placing a button in a grid inside a frame freezes on execution

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have created two frames using Tkinter. In one of the frames I am trying to add a button using a grid. When I run the program, there is no output. Instead it just freezes and I have to kill the process.

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.title("calculator")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.resizable(0,0)

input_field=StringVar()
display_frame=Frame(window).pack(side="top")
button_frame=Frame(window).pack(side="bottom")

text=Entry(display_frame,font=('arial',20,'bold'),textvariable=input_field,justify="right").pack(fill="x",ipady=10)
clear_button=Button(button_frame,text="C").grid(row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

However, if I change the `clear_button` variable as

```
clear_button=Button(button_frame,text="C").pack()
```

I get an output. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot mix `grid` and `pack` inside the same container (a Frame/Window).**

That said you should realize that your *display_frame* and *button_frame* variables are actually `None`! Why, because `Frame(Window)` will return a Frame object, but you have applied the *pack()* function just after that whose return value is *None*.

So basically the `Entry` and the `Button` widgets that you created have `master=None` and that means they are not inside the Frames that you defined, but actually part of the main Window.

Now you can easily see why `clear_button=Button(button_frame,text="C").pack()` was working as now the main window has only one geometry manager namely *pack*.

Here is the working code.

```
from tkinter import * # "Tkinter" on python 2
window=Tk()
window.title("calculator")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.resizable(0,0)

input_field=StringVar()
display_frame=Frame(window)
display_frame.pack(side="top")
button_frame=Frame(window)
button_frame.pack(side="bottom")

Entry(display_frame,font=('arial',20,'bold'),textvariable=input_field,justify="right").pack(fill="x",ipady=10)
Button(button_frame, text="C").grid(row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You made my day!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both **grid** and **pack** method on widgets having same master.

Here, follow the below thread for a detailed understanding :

[python pack() and grid() methods together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267140/python-pack-and-grid-methods-together)

Comment: I understand that, I have referred to the calculator program in https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/gui-tkinter-python which also uses grid in pack and runs fine. Any idea on that?