# Unable to Show Label Image inside a Frame using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

'''

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1255x944")

toplevel_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
Title_frame = ttk.Frame(toplevel_frame)

img= tk.PhotoImage(file="logo.PNG")
img = img.subsample(5, 5)

lbl = tk.Label(Title_frame,image=img, compound = tk.LEFT)
lbl.image = img
lbl.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20, pady=0)

root.mainloop()
```

'''
It is not showing any error but I am unable to show image inside a frame

Comment: You didn't call any layout function on those frames. So they are invisible.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @acw1668 in the comments, the frames namely `toplevel_frame` and `Title_frame` have not been rendered using any layout function([for more info](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/layout-mgt.html)).

The label with the image(i.e. `lbl`) is contained within the `Title_frame` which is within the `toplevel_frame`. So if the `toplevel_frame` and the `Title_frame` are not rendered any widget they contain also would not be rendered. Thus the label with the image(`lbl`) is not rendered.

This can simply be fixed by using any particular layout function to render these frames.

Using grid the two other lines to be added will look like this -:

```
toplevel_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
Title_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

**NOTE:** *The two lines have to be added in the order they are defined, that is the frames have to be rendered in the order of their definition i.e. `toplevel_frame` frame first followed by the `Title_frame` frame followed by the `lbl` label. This will be more clear looking at the full code as provided below.*

With the necessary changes done the full code will look something like this -:

```
# IMPORTS
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# ROOT INITIATION
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1255x944")

# IMAGE OBJECT DEFINITION
img= tk.PhotoImage(file="logo.PNG")
img = img.subsample(5, 5)

# WIDGET DEFINITION
toplevel_frame = ttk.Frame(root)

Title_frame = ttk.Frame(toplevel_frame)

lbl = tk.Label(Title_frame,image=img, compound = tk.LEFT)
lbl.image = img

# LAYOUT MANAGEMENT
toplevel_frame.grid(row=0,column=0) # ADDED.
Title_frame.grid(row=0,column=0) # ADDED.
lbl.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20, pady=0)

# STARTING THE ROOT MAINLOOP
root.mainloop()
```

**NOTE:** *Further while deciding on the layout management function to use keep [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267140/python-pack-and-grid-methods-together) in mind.*