# Centering Items within a LabelFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

[image]

I want to center all the Item's I have within this `LabelFrame`.  The reason it fills this wide is there are other widgets below that are wider than the `LabelFrame` was originally.  `NewCustomerFrame` is a `LabelFrame` object.

```
#notebook
self.nb = Notebook(self, name='notebook')

#admin frame
admin_frame = Frame(self.nb, name='admin')
#new customer
nc_frame = NewCustomerFrame(admin_frame, self.customers)
nc_frame.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=30,ipady=5,fill='x')
''' bla bla bla '''
admin_frame.pack()
self.nb.add(admin_frame, text="Admin",sticky='ew')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to give a minimal working demo if you want others people to help you !

In my point opinion, it is way easier to deal with centering element when using Tkinter grid designer ( see [when using which layout manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966367/tkinter-geometrymanagers-grid-and-pack) ) . You just have to place your elements on a matrix and it's done. The major drawback of grid layout is its difficult to resize elements (no fill option ). We have to place weight on rows and columns ( see `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` ) and stick the controls on every edge (NSWE).

Before going through the code, a warning :  don't mix grid and pack in the same root frame ! In my exemple I use pack to stack the tabs, and grid to manage the elements within the tab itself. I've used [this library for the Notebook class](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/188537-a-simple-tkinter-notebook-like-widget/).

```
root = Tk()


#notebook
nb = notebook(root )


# Admin Tab
admin = Frame( nb() , name='admin') 
admin.grid( sticky=N+S+W+E)

# Every row and column have a wieght of one when resizing (linear transformation)
admin.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
admin.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
admin.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

admin.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
admin.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
admin.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

new_customer = Frame( admin , relief = RIDGE )

# Labels init
Label(admin, text="Name").grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky=N+S+W+E)
Label(admin, text="Type").grid(row=1, column = 0, sticky=N+S+W+E)
Label(admin, text="Date").grid(row=1, column = 2, sticky=N+S+W+E)

 # Elements Init
first_name  = Entry(admin)
middle_name = Entry(admin)
family_name     = Entry(admin)
date        = Entry(admin)

type_box = OptionMenu( admin , "one", "two", "three")


reset_button = Button( admin, text = "Reset Value" )
submit_button = Button( admin, text = "Submit"  )


# Place elements    
first_name.     grid(row=0  , column  =1, sticky=N+S+W+E)
middle_name.    grid(row=0  , column  =2, sticky=N+S+W+E)
family_name.    grid(row=0  , column  =3, sticky=N+S+W+E)
date.       grid(row =1 , column  =3,  sticky=N+S+W+E)
type_box.   grid(row =1  , column  =1, sticky=N+S+W+E)
reset_button.   grid(row =2 , column  = 1 ,sticky=N+S+W+E)
submit_button.  grid(row =2 , column  = 3 , sticky=N+S+W+E)



# Add Tabls
nb.add_screen( admin , "Admin" )
nb.add_screen( Frame(nb()) , "Others" )



if __name__ == "__main__":
        root.mainloop()
```

The app is not perfect (there is no padding, the row aren't expanding) but it should give you a head start.