# setting inner modules in frame using tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

Here's my code and what exactly I'm trying to do is setting the URL label in mid of frame and the entry text next to it, and adding 3 buttons below the URL and entry text field.

```
  import tkinter as tk
  from tkinter import *
  root = tk.Tk()


root.geometry("520x400")

frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="my_first_window", width=400,  height=200, bd=5)
Label(root, text="URL:").grid(row=0, column=1 ,sticky=W)

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0, column=2)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=7, padx=8)

Button(root, text='BACK', command=lambda:print('BACK')).grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(root, text='NEXT', command=lambda:print('NEXT')).grid(row=8, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(root, text='CANCLE', command=lambda:print('CANCLE')).grid(row=8, column=3, sticky=W, pady=4)


mainloop()
```

Comment: There are no `Entry` widgets or `Button` widgets in your code. You also haven't asked a question in your **question**. What can we do to help you here? You need to be more clear.

Comment: i have added the buttons but now i want my frame to be set in middle of the tkinter window and also leaves certain space from the menu bar and tool bar if added @EthanField also i have edit my previous code to new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using the `.grid()` method then you can add the below to your code:

```
for column in range(10):
    Grid.columnconfigure(root, column, weight=1)

for row in range(10):
    Grid.rowconfigure(root, row, weight=1)
```

This will mean that the column's and row's of the grid will have the space available in the window given to them evenly. Using this in conjunction with the `sticky` attribute of `.grid()` will let you achieve the result you are looking for.

---

However, subjectively speaking it may be easier for you to switch over to the `.pack()` method, which (at least in my own opinion) allows for much easier configuration and management of tkinter GUIs.

You could do something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("520x400")

frame1 = LabelFrame(root, text="my_first_window", width=400,  height=200, bd=5)
Label(frame1, text="URL:").pack(side="left", fill="x")

e1 = Entry(frame1)
e1.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
frame1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

Button(root, text='BACK', command=lambda:print('BACK')).pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left", padx=5, pady=5)
Button(root, text='NEXT', command=lambda:print('NEXT')).pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left", padx=5, pady=5)
Button(root, text='CANCLE', command=lambda:print('CANCLE')).pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left", padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

The above makes use of a lot of different new ideas that have been asked and answered too many times here on Stack Overflow so I'm going to link you to [this fantastic answer from Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3968033/4528269).

Comment: thank u so much it really worked for what i was actually trying to do @Ethan Field